# Flutter animate transition when Text data changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Is there a way in Flutter to animate the transition when the data of a `Text` element changes?

I have a `new Text(_value)` element where `_value` changes based on a Slider position. Is there any way to animate the transition so it isn't as "aprupt" as it is when just changing `_value`?

I know there are widgets to animate the transition between two different widgets, but I'm only changing the `data` property of the same `Text` widget.

Comment: The text value may change abruptly but the slider position doesn't. I'd probably feed it's position into an animation controller. Since it and the text are related, does it really matter which one is controlling the animation as long as it animates smoothly?

Comment: But what exactly do I animate? Basically I only have `Text(dataArray[sliderPosition.round()]`. Looks like I'm gonna have to stack all possible Texts and animate the opacity or something... Was hoping there would be a TransitionAnimation that would cover all updates to children or something similar.

Comment: Use a fade between two text widgets, or rotate the display and have it change halfway... what you do is up to you. All I'm saying is that if you want it to be smooth, then use the slider to control the animation OR when the value changes then trigger an animation instead of just updating the value.

Comment: You can use the AnimatedSwitcher for that

Comment: you can check out https://github.com/ibhavikmakwana/FlutterPlayground/blob/master/lib/ui/animatedswitcher/AnimatedSwitcherExample.dart

Comment: https://github.com/ibhavikmakwana/FlutterPlayground/blob/master/preview/AnimatedSwitcher.gif

Answer (score 23):

Wrap up your text widget with an **AnimatedSwitcher** widget and inside the transitionBuilder, define your child.

Inside the child(Text widget), define a key like this:

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  transitionBuilder:
      (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
    return SlideTransition(
      child: child,
      position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: Offset(0.0, -0.5),
              end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
          .animate(animation),
    );
  },
  child: Text(
    userAnswer,
    key: ValueKey<String>(userAnswer),
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45, color: Colors.white),
  ),
)
```

which userAnswer is String.

Answer (score 15):

I needed the same thing so I created a `cross_fade` widget.

https://gist.github.com/cirediew/38abb52e27278dae2b8eba77ed4b3bdc

It takes `initialData` to display the first time.
`data` is your String/double/int/whatever you want to put into your crossfading widget. And the `builder` in which you can create your widget.

It is used like this:

```dart
CrossFade<String>(
    initialData: 'Some String',
    data: myString,
    builder: (value) => Text(value),
),
```

Edit:

Null safe version, renamed to `AnimatedFadeOutIn`:
https://gist.github.com/cirediew/9f68acb7aed1296a232a5f846071d2c3

Comment: call many `setState` is not an idle way.  Use `FadeTransition`

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `AnimatedCrossFade` here is an example:

```
 AnimatedCrossFade(
                crossFadeState: isSelected
                    ? CrossFadeState.showSecond
                    : CrossFadeState.showFirst,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                firstChild: Text(
                  title,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .headline5!
                      .copyWith(color: textColor),
                ),
                secondChild: Text(
                  selectedTitle,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                  style: Theme.of(context).
                         textTheme.
                         headline5!.
                         copyWith(color: selectedColor),
                ),
              ),
```